# Maya's dnoise function: What does it do and how do I implement it?

Tags: c++, maya, noise

I need to write a C++ implementation of the dnoise function from Maya. However, the [documentation for this function](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/index.html?url=Useful_functions_dnoise.htm,topicNumber=d0e176875) is woefully inadequate for describing what this function actually does from an implementation perspective.

So, what does this function actually do? And how do I implement it?

EDIT: Found this in the documentation: "The noise functions return values of a noise field in one, two, and three dimensions. The dnoise command returns the gradient of the noise field in three dimensions."

So what's the difference between the value and the gradient of the noise field?

EDIT 2: Apparently the gradient is the function that returns a vector of partial derivatives.

[Partial Derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)

[Gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)

So that answers what the function needs to do; now the question is how to compute the partial derivative of a noise function.

Comment: Have a look at Gradient Noise.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_noise

Answer (score 1):

If you read the noise function documentation you'll discover that dnoise is producing Perlin noise in three dimensions.

There's a free implementation in C++ available at [flipcode](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Perlin_Noise_Class.shtml)

For more theoretical background about Perlin noise see this [page](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)

Also, Ken Perlin is cool guy. Check out his work! see his [homepage](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/).

Comment: Thanks for the useful links! Lots of good stuff there. But I don't see an exact match to the dnoise function, which takes a vector and returns a vector.